# Use of "create"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "create" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> In present work, proposed design (variable thickness blade) has a
>   higher efficiency than the original design (constant thickness blade)
>   at the high flow coefficient (ϕ=0.275). By using such a Wells turbine,
>   the cleaner air in the environment will be **created** because the
>   amount of fossil fuels consumption and air pollution is decreased more
>   at the high flow coefficient in order to produce the electrical
>   energy.

Comment: There are too many other problems with this text to make it anything other than proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

Although **created** is not absolutely wrong in that context, there are simpler (and more honest) ways of saying

> cleaner air in the environment will be created

The turbines pollute less when they use variable-thickness blades.

A variable thickness blade is more fuel-efficient, which **results in** cleaner air.

[i.e. cleaner than there would be with a blade with worse fuel-efficiency]

Comment: What is your exact meaning of "more fuel-efficient"?

Comment: **fuel-efficiency** is a ratio of "work performed" (whatever the work is) to the amount of fuel consumed to do that work.  If device A is more fuel-efficient than device B, A does the same amount of work as B, but using less fuel.  I'm simply rephrasing your "fuel consumption ... is decreased".